# proof: show that f'(x) is uniformly continuous on I.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Question:
Let I = (a, b) be a nonempty open interval, f is differentiable on I. for each ε > 0, there exists δ > 0 such that for all x, y ∈ (a, b) satisfying 0 < |x − y| < δ we have

$\vert{\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(x)}\vert$  < ε

Show that f ′ is uniformly continuous on I.

I think I need to get $\vert{f'(x) - f'(y)}\vert$ < ε from all the given information but I can't figure out how I should proceed.

Comment: \begin{align}
|f'(x) - f'(y)| & = \bigg |f'(x) - f'(y) + \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} - \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \bigg | \\
& \le \bigg |f'(x) - \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \bigg | + |f'(y) - \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} \bigg | < 2 \epsilon
\end{align}